# The scope and lifetime of static local variable in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int &fun()
{
    static int x = 10;
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
    cout << fun();
    return 0;
}
```

when the above program is run,the output is 30.The integer variable x was returned,as a reference to the main() function and it is assigned the value of 30.But isn't the scope of x limited to the fun() function?;If so,why are we able to change the value of it in main function??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) is limited means any attempt to access `x` **directly** outside the scope is forbidden.

> Within a scope, unqualified name lookup can be used to associate the
>   name with its declaration.

But you can always return a pointer or reference to this variable if variable is alive and you change it through that reference or pointer which points to the same variable. The name of this reference may be anonymous (temporary) or may be bound to some named reference.

About lifetime, it starts when the function containing static variable is called first time and ends when the program end.

Comment: Is the lifetime till end of program? I thought compiler uses logic or what not and cleans up after safe to do so or when it can't possibly be used.

Comment: @marshalcraft That would be interesting, but difficult for compiler to analyse and error prone. There are no brownie points to make the life of compiler writers difficult.

Comment: ha so all those ints and what not are there for life of the program.

Comment: Thanks.confused between lifetime and scope.You made it clear.

Comment: @marshalcraft not all those ints and whatnot, but only static ones. static changes the lifetime of a name, while it does not affect its scope (where its content can be used by that name) that is still limited to the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the scope of `x` *is* limited to `fun()`.

But because that function returns a *reference* to `x`, the caller (i.e. `main`) is able to modify `x` *through* that reference. That's what's happening here: `x` is set to `10` the *first* time the function is entered, but is changed to 30 by the assignment `fun() = 30`.