# Why does static have to be there?

Tags: c++, static

could anyone clarify this piece of code for me?
I've done some research to understand references and static, but I still don't understand what does static do in this example. And why does it have to be there in the first place (If static is missing, the compiler gives warning and program could possibly crash, why?).

```
int & foo(int b)
{
    static int a = 7;


    a += b;
    return a;
}

int main() {

    int & x = foo(0);
    int & y = foo(1);
    cout << (x + y);

}
```

Comment: The function returns a reference to `a`. Without the `static`, `a` is on the stack, so the function returns a reference to what?

Comment: what warning? What exactly did you not understand after reading [some docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static)?

Comment: Possible duplicate, but I'm hesitant to hammer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4643713/10077

Comment: very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Comment: also near-duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37742649/the-scope-and-lifetime-of-static-local-variable-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `static` local variable will have a life-time of the full program. A reference to it will never become invalid.

Otherwise, non-static local variables will "disappear" once they go out of scope (which happens when the function returns), and you can't have a reference to something that doesn't exist.

An important note about `static` local variables and their initialization: They are initialized only *once*, on the first call of the function. The variable will *not* be initialized on further calls, but will keep the last value it had.